# Highstokc range selector input width is decreased in focussed mode

Tags: highcharts

I have enabled range selector, but input width of range selector is decrease when it is in focussed mode and two border are coming. How can I make it fixed for not focussed and focussed mode.

See screenshot below[image]

Comment: Can you recreate the issue on jsfiddle/codepen/plunkr/etc.?

Comment: Ok I ll recreate.. could you tell me how to apply style for inputs in focussed mode? why styles are different

Comment: Check the documentation http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.inputStyle and the demo http://jsfiddle.net/24kw0jky/

Comment: inputStyle will get applied to input for all state. I want styling only for focussed state. Btw I have applied styles using inputStyle attribute but no result.